# how can I change drop down values depending on a different drop down select

Tags: java, javascript, php

I have a servlet load within a php page
here is my php page: reviewing.php

```
if(isset($_GET['x'])){
    $x = $_GET['x'];
}else{
    $x = '';
}

$site = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $Id = "id=".$_GET['id'];
}else{
    $Id = "";
}

$handle = fopen("http://".$site.":8080/Apps/reviewing.php?$Id", "r"); 

$contents = '';

while (!feof($handle)) {

 $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);

}

fclose($handle);

echo $contents;
```

as you can see my php page loads a servlet. The servlet is where the process takes place. It includes JSP and html pages in the servlet as well.

I need to be able to change the value of a dropdown when the option of another dropdown has been changed. they are both separate mysql queries but I need to run the second one only when the dropdown has changed. The reason I am doing this is so I can use the value of dropdown1 as `WHERE` in dropdown2 query.

I tried something like

```
  function reload(form)
  {

      var ID = form.agent.options[form.agent.options.selectedIndex].value;

      return ID;
  }
```

this function goes into `<select onchange="reload(this.form);">` 
then I want to use ID to run the next query

```
<select>
//javascript
if(isset(reload())){
   //JAVA
   run query here WHERE id = ID;

    while(rs.next()){
      outn.print("<option>" + rs.getString("value") + "</option>");
    }
}
</select>
```

thats how I envision it. The other option is to use this in the reload() function

```
self.location='http://exmaple.com/reviewing.php?x=blah&ID=blah;
```

but i dont want to have to keep reloading the page. that is inefficient.

Comment: Would it be possible to explain another way of what you're trying. I don't get it... Maybe you could simplify the problem or try to formulate it generally.

Comment: basically, when I select an option on dropdwon1 I want dropdown2 to be populated with a query using the ID from dropwdown1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok therfore you should write your program like following:

1. handle the select-element onchange event

   - in the select-element onchange-attribut (like you did)
   - with JS
   - with jQuery
2. in this handler you can get the selected Index
3. use it to get the id
4. send an ajax request to a php file to get the data from DB with id as POST data
5. send back the RESPONSE with the data of db (probably you should use json)
6. Use the Response to fill up your select

Here is a little code example:

HTML

```
<select id='select1'>
    <option id='option_1' value='1'>Option 1</option>
    <option id='option_2' value='2'>Option 2</option>
    <option id='option_3' value='3'>Option 3</option>
    <option id='option_4' value='4'>Option 4</option>
</select>

<select id='select2'>

</select>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('select1').onchange = function(){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "id="+this.value           //you can add more data, use & as delemitter

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            fillSelect(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","path/to/php.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}

var fillSelect = function(response){
    //Here you can go through all elements from response 
    //and build new options and append them to Select2
}
```

PHP

```
if (!isset($_POST('id')) die("Submission failed!");

$id = $_POST('id');

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PW, DB);   //assuming you have these static variables, change it for your settings

//use $id now to create the query
$query = "[...]";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

echo json_encode($result);
```

[JSFIDDLE for parts of the code](http://jsfiddle.net/6P9Ah/a)

I hope the php doesn't contain mistakes. I could not test it. If something is wrong then just check wheter spelling is correct and so on...

Comment: can you give an example of how I can do this? I'm a little lost.

Comment: Well, you ask a question like this and then you loose the intrest after half a day...

Comment: my apologies. I haven't had a chance to get back to this project yet. I had an emergency but will get back to it wednesday. I appreciate your input and will test it then.